# Android SDK - Can we connect to new wifi n/w programmatically?

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am trying to connect to a new WIFI network programmatically (not a known n/w to android wifi list). While developing I have found that if the n/w is already known to android, I can easily connect with it, but if the n/w is not known, the app can't connect to n/w even with following lines of code:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager).getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
//remember id
int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
wifiManager.disconnect();
wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
wifiManager.reconnect();
```

I always end up with "Authentication Problem". Am i right in thinking that n/w has to be a known for it to be connected programmatically? Here's how setup my configuration object (Note: The authentication type is WPA).

```
WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
conf.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";   // Please note the quotes. String should contain SSID in quotes
conf.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", networkPwd);
```

Comment: How are you setting up `wifiConfig`, and what is the authentication type?

Comment: @DanielNugent Please look at the updated question. Authentication type is WPA and I have also updated the setup of wifi configuration object.